# Problems joining parent/child node table in MySQL - reduced result set

Tags: mysql, sql, join, parent-child, resultset

I'm having problems populating a table named component_has_component, which refers parent nodes to their children.

I've created a temporary table with both parent and child ids from a Bill of Material Excel sheet and need to look up the unique keys associated with each component.

The query looks as follows:

```
INSERT
INTO   component_has_component
       (parent_component_key, parent_index, child_component_key, child_index, amount)
SELECT c.component_key, c.component_index, p.component_key, p.component_index, t.amount
FROM   component c, component p, temp_comp_has_comp t
WHERE  t.parent = c.component_id 
  AND  t.child = p.component_id;
```

However, this query returns fewer rows than the original temp_comp_has_comp (16 vs. 27) and I cannot seem to find the underlying reason for that.

This is what temp_comp_has_comp looks like:

```
id  parent   child      amt
1   A014_06  A033_06    1
2   A231_01  A033_06    1
3   A230_01  A045_04    2
4   A257_01  A0568      1
5   A231_01  A167_01    1
```

Is there something wrong with the way that I'm joining, e.g. duplicate id's are ommitted?

Comment: Are you sure that all parent and child IDs are actually present in the component table? Perhaps some of them are missing, that would explain why you get less rows.

Comment: Yes, please show some of the rows from `component`.

Comment: Please also post a sample from the `component` table. You are using implicit inner joins here (comma-separated `FROM` clause) but it is possible you need to be using `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, you were right. I completely overlooked that possibility, there was something wrong with our import macro which is now fixed.

As for the component table, 5 entries were missing and now 27 results are returned from the abovementioned query.

Best,
Marius